# magento parameter url of currency

Tags: url-rewrite

I'm new to magento, have been using creloaded, figure it's time to move on to a new e-commerce platform and found this charm at last.

My website have 6 languages and 6 currencies, the base currency is USD and I have GBP, EUR and so on. I do post my products onto Google Base regularly. My problem is I need to be able to specify the currency in URL, i notice each time when we switch currency, the url stay the same and, I would like to know how to set the currency with url?

Answer (score 3):

Magento has a controller which sets the currency: `\\Mage_Directory_CurrencyController::switchAction`

So it is not possible out of the box, but you could easily implement a small observer (google magento observer) which does this for you.

Just copy the code of the controller and throw it in the `controller_action_predispatch` event

```
public function switchAction()
{
    if ($curency = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('currency')) {
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($curency);
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getBaseUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to use this demo  in magento2.4